# how to use PickerBuilder.setRelayUrl(string) in google picker API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I need to get a shareable link to google drive photos and files. Do I need to know this method can be used for that or what can be used for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the defined use for setRelay in [Picker Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference):

> **PickerBuilder.setRelayUrl(string)** - Set the relay URL, used for gadgets.rpc.
>   **Picker.setRelayUrl(string)**  Specify a relay URL to circumvent cross-domain issues.

However to answer your question, you might be looking for [webViewLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource-representations):

> A link only available on public folders for viewing their static web
>   assets (HTML, CSS, JS, etc) via Google Drive's Website Hosting.

This property is returned from a successful API call like [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) or [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).